# What are the memory fences required here?

Tags: parallel-processing, numa, memory-fences

As a classical example for the necessity of memory fences to ensure the correctness of parallel program's execution, the following example is often given:

P1:

```
x = 42;                 //line 1
flag = true;            //line 2
```

P2:

```
while(!flag);
y = x;
```

On one hand, to achieve the best possible performance, processors try to (legally) reorder instructions in such a way that the reordered sequence of instructions has the exact same effect as the original one, when considering a sequential execution.
On the other hand, to ensure the correctness of sequentially executing the sequence of instructions, control dependencies must be respected.
From this point of view, isn't the **while** statement executed by P2 a control dependency?
And if so, then the only memory fence that would be required is a Store|Store fence between line 1 and line 2 of P1, right?